# How to translate date in "Date Range Picker" where month is formated as string?

Tags: javascript, translation, date-formatting, daterangepicker

I am using javascript date range picker component (https://www.daterangepicker.com/).
Localization is well handled on all levels except in one case I do not know how to correctly set it up.

On the screenshot you can see that everything is in german, except for the one marked with arrow.

[image]

This value is set by

```
locale: {
  format: 'MMMM D, YYYY',
```

I do not know how I can translate the `MMMM` part.

Here is the whole daterangepicker code.

```
        function ranges_locale($langcode) {
          var _default_ranges = {
            next_7_days: [moment(), moment().add(7, 'days')],
            tomorrow: [moment().add(1, 'days'), moment().add(1, 'days')],
            today: [moment(), moment()],
            yesterday: [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
            last_7_days: [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
            last_30_days: [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
            this_month: [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
            last_month: [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
          };

          var _ranges = {
            'en': {
              'Next 7 Days': _default_ranges.next_7_days,
              'Tomorrow': _default_ranges.tomorrow,
              'Today': _default_ranges.today,
              'Yesterday': _default_ranges.yesterday,
              'Last 7 Days': _default_ranges.last_7_days,
              'Last 30 Days': _default_ranges.last_30_days,
              'This Month': _default_ranges.this_month,
              'Last Month': _default_ranges.last_month,
            },
            'de': {
              'Nächste 7 Tage': _default_ranges.next_7_days,
              'Morgen': _default_ranges.tomorrow,
              'Heute': _default_ranges.today,
              'Gestern': _default_ranges.yesterday,
              'Letzte 7 Tage': _default_ranges.last_7_days,
              'Letzte 30 Tage': _default_ranges.last_30_days,
              'Dieser Monat': _default_ranges.this_month,
              'Letzter Monat': _default_ranges.last_month,
            }
          };


        target.daterangepicker({
          "opens": "center",
          "maxSpan": {
            "days": 366
          },
          locale: {
            format: 'MMMM D, YYYY',
            applyLabel: tc('Apply'),
            cancelLabel: tc('Cancel'),
            customRangeLabel: tc('Custom Range'),
            daysOfWeek: [
              tc('Su'), tc('Mo'), tc('Tu'), tc('We'), tc('Th'), tc('Fr'), tc('Sa')
            ],
            monthNames: [
              tc('January'), tc('February'), tc('March'), tc('April'), tc('May'), tc('June'), tc('July'), tc('August'), tc('September'), tc('October'), tc('November'), tc('December')
            ],
            firstDay: 1
          },
          ranges: ranges_locale(currentLanguage),
          "alwaysShowCalendars": true,
          "startDate": target.attr('start-date'),
          "endDate": target.attr('end-date'),
        });
```

Thank you.

Comment: What `ranges_locale(currentLanguage)` does exactly? Can you show me the code?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito I added requested code into question description (it was too long for comment). It is jut a "mapping" function that return different labels for preselected time ranges.

Comment: @zanvidmar can we translate numerical date as well? thanks in advance

Comment: @SachinJagtap can you plese be more specific? What is numerical date? Do you mean format `(format: 'MMMM D, YYYY',)`?

Comment: @zanvidmar no, I mean the date (1,2,3, 4, 5,....31) to respective language.

Comment: @SachinJagtap I am sorry, but to what would you like to translate numbers?
If the source is "1" what would be the translation? What am I missing here :)

Comment: @zanvidmar like this: https://www.omniglot.com/language/numerals2.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date range picker is using moment under the hood so you can do some [customisation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/) to replace the english month to german month.

Play the code below to see if it can do what you want:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2018 - 01/15/2018" />

    <script>
        
        $(function () {

            // update locale to de and customize the MMM, MMMM translation
            moment.updateLocale("de", {
                months : ['Januar','Februar','März','April','Mai','Juni','Juli','August','September','Oktober','November','Dezember'],
                monthsShort : ['Jan', 'Feb', 'März', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dez']
            });
        
            $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
                "opens": "center",
                "maxSpan": {
                    "days": 366
                },
                locale: {
                    format: 'MMMM D, YYYY',
                    applyLabel: tc('Apply'),
                    cancelLabel: tc('Cancel'),
                    customRangeLabel: tc('Custom Range'),
                    daysOfWeek: [
                        tc('Su'), tc('Mo'), tc('Tu'), tc('We'), tc('Th'), tc('Fr'), tc('Sa')
                    ],
                    monthNames: [
                        tc('January'), tc('February'), tc('March'), tc('April'), tc('May'), tc('June'), 
                        tc('July'), tc('August'), tc('September'), tc('October'), tc('November'), tc('December')
                    ],
                    firstDay: 1
                },
                // ranges: ranges_locale(currentLanguage),
                "alwaysShowCalendars": true,
                // "startDate": today, //target.attr('start-date'),
                // "endDate": target.attr('end-date'),
            });
        })

        const germanMapping = {
            'Su': 'So',
            'Mo': 'Mo',
            'Tu': 'Di',
            'We': 'Mi',
            'Th': 'Do',
            'Fr': 'Fr',
            'Sa': 'Sa',

            'January': 'Januar',
            'February': 'Februar',
            'March': 'März',
            'April': 'April',
            'May': 'Mai',
            'June': 'Juni',
            'July': 'Juli',
            'August': 'August',
            'September': 'September',
            'October': 'Oktober',
            'November': 'November',
            'December': 'Dezember',

            "Apply": "Anwenden",
            "Cancel": "Stornieren"
        }
        const tc = (val) => germanMapping[val]
        
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `DataRangePicker` manages date using `moment`, if you want to change bottom label language you should add this import:

`import "moment/locale/de";`

and the result is:

[image]

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/daterangepicker-forked-bhlkb?file=/src/DateRangePicker.js) a codesandbox example.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a direct solution, but a workaround.

What if you change the months with jQuery? You get somehow the current language (one way is probably with `<html lang="en">`) and then change the month string.

It's not the nicest solution, but it should work.